# in jupyter notebook Getting error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: scikit-learn

I’m using sklearn version 0.21.3 and trying to import `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection`:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

But I’m getting this error:

> OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label
> syntax is incorrect:
> 'C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip:C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python'

Answer (score 0):

Hi All i got the answer for the issue
i just removed the existing scikit-learn package and reinstall the latest version

Note :if we remove the existing scikit-learn package some other package also get removed so please check which packages has been removed if any please reinstall those also

In my case "seaborn" got removed automatically when i removed existing scikit-learn
Then again i reinstalled seaborn also